# GridBag not displaying all components in row

Tags: java, swing, gridbaglayout

I've implemented a `JPanel` using a `GridBagLayout` as follows:

```
fileSelectionDetails = new JPanel();
fileSelectionGridBagLayout = new GridBagLayout();
fileSelectionDetails.setLayout(fileSelectionGridBagLayout);


JLabel lblFile1 = new JLabel("File 1:");
JTextField txtFile1Path = new JTextField();    
JButton btnBrowseFile1 = new JButton("Browse...");

addComponentToFileSelectionGrid(lblFile1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 20, 100, GridBagConstraints.NONE, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
addComponentToFileSelectionGrid(txtFile1Path, 1, 0, 3, 1, 60, 100, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);
addComponentToFileSelectionGrid(btnBrowseFile1, 2, 0, 1, 1, 20, 100, GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL, GridBagConstraints.WEST);

private void addComponentToFileSelectionGrid(Component component, int gridX, int gridY,
                            int gridWidth, int gridHeight, int weightX, 
                            int weightY, int fill, int anchor) {

    GridBagConstraints constraint = new GridBagConstraints();
    constraint.gridx = gridX;
    constraint.gridy = gridY;
    constraint.gridwidth = gridWidth;
    constraint.gridheight = gridHeight;
    constraint.weightx = weightX;
    constraint.weighty = weightY;       
    constraint.fill = fill;
    constraint.anchor = anchor;
    fileSelectionGridBagLayout.setConstraints(component, constraint);
    fileSelectionDetails.add(component);
}
```

I want to see my components laid out as follows:

[image]

However, what I'm actually seeing is:

[image]

i.e. the 'Browse...' button is missing! Why is this?

Comment: Who knows. Maybe the frame isn't big enough to display all the components. Post a proper [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Just figured it out...it's because the `gridx` constraint property of my button is 2 however the text field spans 3 cells of the grid, covering the button.

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think the `gridWidth` mattered when you only had a single row of components. To make the text field larger, just use: `new JTextField(20)` when you create the text field. It will calculate a size to hold 20 "W" characters.

Comment: Also, if you want to make components size relative to one another you can check out the [Relative Layout](https://tips4java.wordpress.com/2008/11/02/relative-layout/) which is easier to use than the GridBagLayout. However, I wouldn't really recommend using relative sizes since the label and button should be displayed at their preferred size so text doesn't get truncated. Only the text field should grow/shrink as the frame size changes.

Comment: @camickr Thank you for your suggestions, I'll bear them in mind! The grid coordinates were the issue in my case.

Comment: Well, I'm just suggesting the code isn't working as you expect. The text field is not 3 times the size of the label and the button. The way GridBagLayout works is that each component is given its preferred size. So in your code the preferred size of the text field is 0. Then as the frame size is increased the extract space goes to the components. So in you increase the width by 100, the text field get 60 more pixels and the button and label each get 20. So the total size is not in the ratio that you expect.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your drawing, I’m guessing you don’t want relative widths at all.  It appears you want the label and button to be their preferred sizes, and the JTextField to stretch to take up all of the width not used by the label and button.

As camickr suggested, you should give the JTextField a meaningful preferred size by initializing it with a column count, like `new JTextField(20)`.

You can then take advantage of some useful aspects of GridBagLayout and GridBagConstraints:

- The default value of gridx and gridy is RELATIVE, which means each component you add is placed to the right of the last one added.  Which just happens to be exactly what you want.  Therefore, you should not set gridx or gridy at all.
- The default value of gridwidth and gridheight is 1.  This is what you want.  GridBagLayout cells are flexible, so setting one component’s gridwidth to 3 does *not* make it three times wider than a component whose gridwidth is 1.  The width of a cell, or span of cells, depends entirely on what it contains.
- When you add a component to a GridBagLayout, the GridBagConstraints object is cloned inside the GridBagLayout.  This means you can safely reuse the same GridBagConstraints object over and over, changing just the fields that need to change.

With this knowledge, your code can be simplified to:

```
fileSelectionDetails = new JPanel(new GridBagLayout());

JLabel lblFile1 = new JLabel("File 1:");
JTextField txtFile1Path = new JTextField(20);
JButton btnBrowseFile1 = new JButton("Browse\u2026");

txtFile1Path.setMinimumSize(txtFile1Path.getPreferredSize());

GridBagConstraints constraints = new GridBagConstraints();
constraints.fill = GridBagConstraints.HORIZONTAL;

constraints.weight = 0;
fileSelectionDetails.add(lblFile1, constraints);
constraints.weight = 1;
fileSelectionDetails.add(txtFile1Path, constraints);
constraints.weight = 0;
fileSelectionDetails.add(btnBrowseFile1, constraints);
```

Comment: That's a very good insight and you're correct - I do want the text field to fill the remaining width. Thanks for your suggestions!

Answer (score 1):

You define gridWidth=3 for txtFile1Path but add btnBrowseFile1 at gridX=2. You must set addComponentToFileSelectionGrid(btnBrowseFile1, 4 ...etc.

Comment: (1+), yes, otherwise the button and text field are painted in the same location, which is easier to see if the logic is changed to `new JTextField(20)`. You will see the text field is painted on top of the button.